# Gets undefined when trying to access a null value inside a nested object in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects, nested-object, jsobject

I have an object

```
const data={a:'value1',b:{c:'null'}}
```

Now when I try to access 'c', I get 'undefined' but I am getting 'b'.
I tried accessing like this:

```
console.log(data.b) returns {c:'null'} but
console.log(data.b.c) returns undefined
```

Comment: try `this.data.b.c`

Comment: `console.log(data.b.c)` should give you the result `'value2'`. I don't see an issue here?

Comment: unfortunately, it's not working in a vue component...but its working on other components..lol

Comment: @PashupatiSah please share a [mcve] of the issue. This isn't minimal because it's not inside a vue component

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
let {c} = data.b;
console.log(c);
```

It will resolve your problem.

**Update:**
In vue components, sometimes you are not able to fetch nested object like this

```
data.b.c
```

so you have to use this strategy to access nested object attribute. like this

```
let {c} = data.b
```